# Can't start the local fabric in VSC environment when trying to deploy smart contract

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, ibm-blockchain, ibp-vscode-extension

When using the IBM Blockchain Extension for VS Code; I wrote a sample smart contract and packaged it. But when I try to start the local fabric environment, I get an error saying:
`Failed to start Local Fabric: Failed to execute command "cmd" with arguments "/c, start.cmd" return code 1`

I was following the IBM tutorials for blockchain and installed all required software tools for the extension as listed by IBM in the following [link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=IBMBlockchain.ibm-blockchain-platform&cm_mmc=OSocial_Wechat-_-Blockchain%20and%20Watson%20Financial%20Services_Blockchain-_-WW_WW-_-VS%20code%20link%20on%20IBM%20domain%20to%20VS%20code&cm_mmca1=000026VG&cm_mmca2=10008691):

N/A

This is part of the error:

```
[9/2/2019 8:09:46 PM] [INFO] C:\Users\sufij\.fabric-vscode\environments\local_fabric>echo Hyperledger Fabric started in  seconds.
[9/2/2019 8:09:46 PM] [INFO] Hyperledger Fabric started in  seconds
[9/2/2019 8:09:46 PM] [INFO] C:\Users\sufij\.fabric-vscode\environments\local_fabric>rem Check to see if the channel already exists 
[9/2/2019 8:09:46 PM] [INFO] C:\Users\sufij\.fabric-vscode\environments\local_fabric>docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" fabricvscodelocalfabric_peer0.org1.example.com peer channel getinfo -c mychannel 
[9/2/2019 8:09:46 PM] [INFO] Error: No such container: fabricvscodelocalfabric_peer0.org1.example.com
[9/2/2019 8:09:46 PM] [INFO] C:\Users\sufij\.fabric-vscode\environments\local_fabric>if errorlevel 1 
[9/2/2019 8:09:46 PM] [INFO] (
[9/2/2019 8:09:46 PM] [INFO] rem Create the channel  
[9/2/2019 8:09:46 PM] [INFO]  docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" fabricvscodelocalfabric_peer0.org1.example.com peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:17050 -c mychannel -f /etc/hyperledger/configtx/channel.tx  
[9/2/2019 8:09:46 PM] [INFO]  rem Update the channel with the anchor peers  
[9/2/2019 8:09:46 PM] [INFO]  docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" fabricvscodelocalfabric_peer0.org1.example.com peer channel update -o orderer.example.com:17050 -c mychannel -f /etc/hyperledger/configtx/Org1MSPanchors.tx  
[9/2/2019 8:09:46 PM] [INFO]  rem Join peer0.org1.example.com to the channel.  
[9/2/2019 8:09:46 PM] [INFO]  docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" fabricvscodelocalfabric_peer0.org1.example.com peer channel join -b mychannel.block 
[9/2/2019 8:09:46 PM] [INFO] ) 
[9/2/2019 8:09:46 PM] [INFO] Error: No such container: fabricvscodelocalfabric_peer0.org1.example.com
[9/2/2019 8:09:46 PM] [INFO] Error: No such container: fabricvscodelocalfabric_peer0.org1.example.com
[9/2/2019 8:09:46 PM] [INFO] Error: No such container: fabricvscodelocalfabric_peer0.org1.example.com
[9/2/2019 8:09:46 PM] [ERROR] Failed to start Local Fabric: Error: Failed to execute command "cmd" with  arguments "/c, start.cmd" return code 1
```

Comment: can you provide a bit more info about your environment. Such as what version of windows are you running ? are you using docker for windows or docker toolbox ?

Comment: Hi david_k, I use Windows 10 Pro Build 1903. I installed all the prerequisites as per the extension guidlines. I installed the Docker for windows and ran it separately as well just to test. This is my environment. IBM Blockchain Platform Extension Version: 1.0.8
Visual Studio Code version: 1.0.8
Environment name and version (e.g. Node.js v8.12.0, npm v6.4.1):
Operating System and version: Windows 10, 64bit
Link to project: sample tutorials

Comment: can you try the following commands to get output `docker ps -a` and also `docker logs fabricvscodelocalfabric_peer0.org1.example.com`

Comment: Hi, after I ran these commands, I got the following outputs:                        C:\Users\sufij>docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
     NAMES

C:\Users\sufij>docker logs fabricvscodelocalfabric_peer0.org1.example.com
Error: No such container: fabricvscodelocalfabric_peer0.org1.example.com